# How to refactor this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, refactoring, readability

I created the following, that works, but it seems very cryptic. Is there a way to write it in a more Ruby-esque or understandable way?

This method removes the lower factors below a number. So, `10.high_factors` returns `[6,7,8,9,10]`. 6 is divisible by 2, so 2 is removed. There are no multiples greater than 6 on the list, so it stays.

```
class Fixnum
  def high_factors
    # Get the numbers that are not divisible by lower ones below self
    list = (2..self).to_a
    2.upto(self).each do |i|
      ((i+1)..self).each { |j| list.delete i if j.is_divisible_by? i }
    end

    list
  end

  def is_divisible_by? divisor
    self % divisor == 0
  end
end
```

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I don't understand this... why not just return [self/2+1 .. self]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of your method will always be a list of the numbers from `(N/2) + 1` to `N`.

For every `i<=(N/2)`, `2*i` will also be on the list.

For every `j >= (N/2)+1` on the list, there will not be a `k=x*j` on it where x is an integer greater than 1, because `2*j > N`.

Therefore, if your method returns just `((self/2 + 1)..self).to_a` it will also work as you wish.

Comment: Although this did not refactor any Ruby code, it really is the best answer because it uses math to prove correctness.

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Just removing numbers that are divisible by upper ones.

```
class Fixnum
  def high_factors
    # Get the numbers that are not divisible by lower ones below self
    (2..self).reject do |i|
      (i+1..self).any? { |j| j.divisible_by?(i) }
    end
  end

  def divisible_by?(divisor)
    self % divisor == 0
  end
end
```

ps: in ruby, it is common to omit the 'is_' at the beginning of boolean function since we can add the ?

Answer (score 1):

Heres mine

```
def high_factors
  ary = (2..self).to_a
  ary.reject do |factor|
    ary.index {|num| num != factor and num % factor == 0}
  end
end
```

It works cause Array#index returns nil if it can't find a suitable match.